# Image change on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi, I have a HTML image that is setup like this:

```
<input id="img" type="image" src="">
```

How can I change `src` on hover?

.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple google search will show you many examples on how to do this.

Comment: Also ther are no explanation related to html. please give

Comment: @AaronS however how many of those examples are current?

Comment: @mplungjan Are you suggesting that you shouldn't do your own research and try to solve it for yourself because you may find out of date solutions? That seems to violate the "Do Your Homework" section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expecting an item to be hovered on i suggest this:

```
   $('.item').mouseover(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#img").attr("src",id);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#img").hover(function(){
      $(this).attr("src","img1.jpg");
   },function(){
      $(this).attr("src","img2.jpg");
   });
});
</script>
<input id="img" type="image" src="">
```

Comment: Sorry - my bad! [.on("hover")](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes) is deprecated, .hover is not

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery for this tag

```
<input id="img1" type="image" src="">

$("#img1").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("blue");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("blue");
});
```

in css class you can write src for this input image tag.

Comment: When i used hover there was an error in console.log. Using mouseover worked smoothly instead